Text field value to appear in a Look up field
Good day everyone!
I am trying to get the value I input in a text field to a look up field. Like whenever I input or enter a value that is existing to my  custom object, it should appear in the look up field automatically.
That said, I created a record triggered flow wherein it will be triggered if the Application record's Preferred program field is updated and the value that is entered should reflect in the Lookup field I added in my opportunity object. Below is the Record triggered flow I created. As you can see, I am getting the records from the custom object "Mapua Programs" where all courses are listed and in my filter you'll there that I am calling it via Id equals to the value I'll enter in the preferred program field from my Application record.
When I tested this, I received the error below:
An Error Occurred with Your "Test flow for mapua program" Flow
You’ve received this email because an error occurred while your "Test flow for mapua program" flow was running. Debug this flow in Flow Builder.
Error element Mapua_Programs_Update_Get_Records (FlowRecordLookup).
This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: FROM Mapua_Program__c WHERE ((Id = 'BS Business Administration ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:41 invalid ID field: BS Business Administration - Master in Business Analytics. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
Please let me know what I can change with the flow I created or what are the things need to be added. Thank you!


the error message is giving you the details you need to know/fix: invalid ID field: BS Business Administration - Master in Business Analytics. try changing the field you are using on the criteria to a text field that contains that value (Name perhaps?)
